# why selinux with chromedriver crashed when i wanna get a website in centos?

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a robot in Python languages with using Selinux and Chromedriver to make a request to the web page and return the results via Python Flask as a webservice.
But the problem here is that it works on Windows without any problems. but it's crashed on Centos and Ubuntu Os.
After checking, I saw that I could not get the destination site in Linux versions of either Centos or Ubuntu via the Wget or Curl commands, etc. The sites are displayed in the browser but are not available through the terminal.
website url is :
"https://www.prodirectrunning.com/p/nike-air-zoom-tempo-next-percent-barely-volt-black-volt-hyper-orange-mens-shoes-243713/"

[Wget Request in Centos OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvZbE.png)

[Wget Request in Ubuntu Os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g584q.png)

Comment: `wget`, `curl` may use different headers (ie. `user-agent`) and they can't run JavaScript - so server may detect that it is not real human. You should check it in Chrome on Linux - if it is installed.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if Selinux and Chromedriver crashed then you should show full error message in question.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on `Linux Mint 20` (based on `Ubuntu 20.04`)

Python module `requests` doesn't work with standard headers but if I use header `'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'` then it works.

```
import requests
import lxml.html

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://www.prodirectrunning.com/p/nike-air-zoom-tempo-next-percent-barely-volt-black-volt-hyper-orange-mens-shoes-243713/'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.url)
print(r.history)

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
items = soup.xpath('//img/@src')

for i in items:
    print(i)
```

The same is with `curl` - it needs header `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0` to work.

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' https://www.prodirectrunning.com/p/nike-air-zoom-tempo-next-percent-barely-volt-black-volt-hyper-orange-mens-shoes-243713/
```

The same is with `wget` - it needs header `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0` to work.

```
wget --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0' https://www.prodirectrunning.com/p/nike-air-zoom-tempo-next-percent-barely-volt-black-volt-hyper-orange-mens-shoes-243713/
```

Comment: New idea. Never used partial `User-Agent` strings before.